# Exception Handler Interceptor

Tags: quarkus

My interceptor is not catching the exceptions thrown by intercepted method, the interceptor is being invoked, but when the method throws an Exceptions seems that Quarkus is handling it, and my catch block is never executed.

Is there a way to handle exceptions instead of using JAX-RS ExceptionMapper?

Thanks

```
@HandleError(domain = Domain.NONE)
@Interceptor
@Priority(10)
public class HandleErrorInterceptor {
    @Inject
    LoggingHelper log;
    @Inject
    SystemParameters params;
    @Inject
    ErrorHelper err;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object catchErrors(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        if (!Result.class.isAssignableFrom(context.getMethod().getReturnType()))
            err.raise(903L, context.getMethod());

        HandleError handleError = context.getMethod().getAnnotation(HandleError.class);

        if (handleError == null) {
            return context.proceed();
        }

        Object result = null;

        try {
            result = context.proceed();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            SystemMessage sysMsg; //NEVER EXECUTED WHEN AN EXCEPTION IS TROWN

            if (ex instanceof ServiceRuntimeException)
                sysMsg = ((ServiceRuntimeException) ex).getSystemMessage();
            else {
                sysMsg = params.getSystemMessage(999L);

                log.error(handleError.domain(), ex, ex.getMessage());

                result = context.getMethod().getReturnType().getConstructor().newInstance();
                ((Result) result).setStatusCode(sysMsg.getCode());
                ((Result) result).setStatusMessage(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this interceptor? Also, can you show how it is being used?